# add object to an existing array of objects React Recoil

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

i want to add a new object to an array of objects when id does not match in react recoil

```
const [cart, setCart] = useRecoilState(cartItems)
```

object {id:1, quantity:1, productName:'apple'}

```
const addToCart =(object) => {
        
        if(cart.length==0){
            setCart([object])
        }
        else{
            let data = cart.map(items=>
                {
                    if(items.id == object.id )
                    {
                        return {...items, quantity:items.quantity + cartData.quantity}
                    }else
                    {
                        
                    }
                })                
            setCart(data)
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your question or your problem?

Comment: its a shopping cart want to add a new item , if item exists already just increase its qty

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
findIndex()
```

to find an element that satisfies your condition. It returns -1 if it can't find anything.

```
const index = cart.findIndex(item => item.index == object.id);
if (index == -1) setCart([...cart, object])
else ...
```